# Move HTML Canvas by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I'm trying to copy  element from one  in my page to another (via javascript). It's successfully copied but appeared empty.

How to copy/move canvas with content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the spec tells that a canvas is cleared when resized, I guess it is the same when cloned in the DOM too. So you need to get the image data with getImageData and put it back with putImageData

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas).